# Capitalizing each words with chr and ord

Tags: python-3.x, letter, capitalize, chr, ord

First I have to receive a string from the user. The function would be capitalizing the introduced string object. It would make the words start with uppercased characters and all remaining characters have lower case. Here is what I did:

```
ssplit = s.split()
for z in s.split():
    if ord(z[0]) < 65 or ord(z[0])>90:
        l=(chr(ord(z[0])-32))
        new = l + ssplit[1:]
        print(new)
    else:
        print(s)
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It helps to inspect variable state by printing stuff: e.g. `print(ssplit)` will show you that it's a list, while `print(l)` will print a string. You can't concatenate a string and a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.title()` as suggested by @Pyer is nice. If you need to use `chr` and `ord` you should get your variables right - see *comments* in code:

```
s = "this is a demo text"
ssplit = s.split()

# I dislike magic numbers, simply get them here:
small_a = ord("a") # 97
small_z = ord("z")

cap_a = ord("A")   # 65

delta = small_a - cap_a

for z in ssplit :  # use ssplit here - you created it explicitly
    if small_a <= ord(z[0]) <= small_z:
        l = chr(ord(z[0])-delta)
        new = l + z[1:]            # need z here - not ssplit[1:]
        print(new) 
    else:
        print(s)
```

Output:

```
This
Is
A
Demo
Text
```

Comment: It solved my problem entirely, thank you so much. But here is what I couldn't understand; although the case of the letters is mixed, for example, even if we write ProGRamming when we run the program we get 'Programming'. I mean, at which line did we get the other letters to be small?

Comment: @Ch nowhere -it only ever corrects the first letter and take the remainder "as is" - if you need to lower case all others you would have to correct any non-lower case as well - or simpy do: `ssplit = s.lower().split()` so you only have lower case letters to start with

Answer (score 1):

There are many python methods that could solve this easily for you. For example, the `str.title()` will capitalize the start of every word in the given string. If you wanted to ensure that all others were lowercase, you could first do `str.lower()` and then `str.title()`.

```py
s = 'helLO how ARE YoU'
s.lower()
s.capitalize()
# s = 'Hello How Are You'
```